# iPhone custom UITableviewcontroller initialization problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

The items array in my uitableview custom controller never gets filled from tmp array! debug hits the init method but nothing changed in self.items array?

in rootcontroller:

```
MultiSelectionTableViewController *multiSelectionViewController = [[MultiSelectionTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MultiSelectionTableViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:multiSelectionViewController animated:YES];       
[multiSelectionViewController release];
```

in MultiSelectionTableViewController

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *items;
@synthesize items;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
 self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  if (self) {

    NSArray *tmp;
    tmp = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Yes", @"No", @"Why not?", @"Depends..", nil];

    [self.items addObjectsFromArray:tmp];

 }
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to alloc/init your array in the custom VC.

Do :

```
self.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Yes", @"No", @"Why not?", @"Depends..", nil];
```

instead.

Or,

```
NSArray *tmp;
tmp = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Yes", @"No", @"Why not?", @"Depends..", nil];
self.items = tmp;
```

Comment: tnx but then what is the purpose of @property and @syntehize I thought they allocate automatically and retain the object

Comment: surely they retain your object, as long as the property is said to retain. But they don't alloc/init anything, it just release the previous one and retain the new one

Comment: I understand it is easy for arrays maybe, what if I want to use my custom object, do I have to make each time [[customObject alloc] init] ?

Answer (score 1):

`self.items` is `nil` as it isn't allocated and initialized so its not filled or added to. You should do

```
self.items = tmp;
```

or directly

```
self.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Yes", @"No", @"Why not?", @"Depends..", nil];
```

Comment: tnx but then what is the purpose of @property and @syntehize I thought they allocate automatically and retain the object

Comment: They just create the methods i.e. `- (NSArray *)items` and `-(void)setItems:(NSArray *)` which are implicitly called when you use the dot notation. They do not create the object itself.